# Retrieve textStatus value in $.ajaxError method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to remove my $.ajax error handler function and use $.ajaxError instead. Everything works fine but I can't find textStatus value in global error handler.
Old error handling:

```js
$.ajax({
    ...
    },
    error:
        function (data, textStatus, xmlHttpRequest)
        {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
});
```

New error handling:

```js
$(document).ajaxError(
    function errorHandler(event, xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
    {
        alert(fetch textStatus?);
    }
```

How can I fetch textStatus value in ajaxError method?

Comment: @mgraph xhr.statusText and textStatus in error handler are different values. textStatus can be timeout, error, parseerror and xhr.statusText returns HTTP status code text. I forgot to mention that I use jquery 1.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

I think `xhr` object  has `statusText` property, you can try that.

```
$(document).ajaxError(
    function errorHandler(event, xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
    {
        alert(xhr.statusText);
    }
);
```

Note:
`status` and `statusText` of xhr will be populated only when there is server generated error with http status code returned. However for jQuery generated error(timeout, parsererror, notmodified) these fields will be empty. I think you should handle this condition in your code.

Comment: Please, take a look at my comment.